# What is {} in assignment?

Tags: go

In Go, when assigning multiple values to an array, braces **{....}** is used. What is this braces? Is it anonymous struct?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var string_array [4]string = [4]string {"X", "Y", "Z", "W"}
    var int_array [5]int = [5]int {1,2,3}

    fmt.Println(string_array)
    fmt.Println(int_array)
}
```

`{"X", "Y", "Z", "W"}` is the same as below and Go runtime is doing an implicit conversion?

```
    type anonymous struct {
        _0 string
        _1 string
        _2 string
        _3 string
    }
    var anon anonymous = anonymous{"X", "Y", "Z", "W"}
```

Why not using `["X", "Y", "Z", "W"]` if it is an array?

- [multiple assignment from array or slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934611/multiple-assignment-from-array-or-slice)
- [Go array initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729736/go-array-initialization)

Where in the [Golang specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec) is this syntax explained?

Comment: The answer shows where it is in the spec, but this is even covered in the tour: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's documented in [the Go language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec) under "[Composite literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)" (emphasis mine):

> Composite literals construct values for structs, arrays, slices, and maps and create a new value each time they are evaluated. They consist of the type of the literal **followed by a brace-bound list of elements**. Each element may optionally be preceded by a corresponding key.

Where "brace-bound" refers to the values being delimited with `{` and `}` as per your posted code.

From the grammar spec:

```
CompositeLit  = LiteralType LiteralValue .
LiteralType   = StructType | ArrayType | "[" "..." "]" ElementType |
                SliceType | MapType | TypeName .
LiteralValue  = "{" [ ElementList [ "," ] ] "}" .        <-- This production-rule, right here
ElementList   = KeyedElement { "," KeyedElement } .
KeyedElement  = [ Key ":" ] Element .
Key           = FieldName | Expression | LiteralValue .
FieldName     = identifier .
Element       = Expression | LiteralValue .
```